# Solving Systems of Linear Equations using Eigen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm currently working on a fluid simulation in C++, and part of the algorithm is to solve a sparse system of linear equations. People recommended using the library Eigen for this. I decided to test it out using this short program that I wrote:

```
#include <Eigen/SparseCholesky>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> triplets;
    triplets.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(0, 0, 1));
    triplets.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(0, 1, -2));
    triplets.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(1, 0, 3));
    triplets.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(1, 1, -2));

    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(2, 2);
    A.setFromTriplets(triplets.begin(), triplets.end());

    Eigen::VectorXd b(2);
    b[0] = -2;
    b[1] = 2;

    Eigen::SimplicialCholesky<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> chol(A);
    Eigen::VectorXd x = chol.solve(b);

    std::cout << x[0] << ' ' << x[1] << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

It gives it these two equations:

x - 2y = -2

3x - 2y = 2

The correct solution is:

x = 2

y = 2

But the problem is that when the program runs, it outputs:
0.181818 -0.727273

Which is totally wrong! I have been debugging this for hours, but it's a very short program and I'm following the tutorial on the Eigen website exactly. Does anybody know what is causing this issue?

P.S. I know that the classes I'm using are for sparse matrices, but the only difference between those and the normal Matrix classes is the way the elements are stored.

Comment: You have built a transposed matrix

Comment: @n.m. I thought that might be it, but even when I transpose it I still get the wrong answer :/

Comment: @n.m. What are you saying? These answers still don’t work even when I transpose the coefficient matrix

Comment: Hmm no sorry I messed up my math. This is a solution not for a transposed matrix, but for (1,3,3,-2).

Comment: @n.m. Wow that’s really strange, do you have any idea why

Comment: Which is only logical, as simplicial Cholesky only works for self-adjoint matrices! It is also deprecated in Eigen.

Comment: @n.m. Is there an algorithm in Eigen that works on non Hermitian matrices that I should use instead?

Comment: @n.m. I found one that works called SparseLU, are there better alternatives?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Eigen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SimplicialCholesky` is for symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices, the matrix you assembled is not even symmetric. By default it only reads the entries in the lower triangular part ignoring the others, so it solved:

```
x + 3y = -2
3x -2y = 2
```

As you noticed, for non-symmetric square problems you need to use a direct solver based on LU or `BICGSTAB` in the world of iterative solvers. This is all summarized in the [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html).

Answer (score -1):

You should use a solver capable to process non-symmetric sparse matrices. Another possible approach is to seek a solution not of the original system [A]x=b, but [A]T*[A]x=[A]T*b, where [A]T stands for the [A] transpose. The latter system's matrix is symmetric and positive definite (as long as [A] is non-singular). The only shortcoming would be the fact that [A]T[A] may be rather ill-conditioned if the original [A] is not "good" in that sense. Just an example of software designed to solve such problems: 
http://members.ozemail.com.au/~comecau/CMA_LS_Sparse.htm